# Flex wrap creates a vertical scrolling whenever bootstrap 5 dropdown is clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Whenever the dropdown is activated on click, there's a vertical scroll instead of the dropdown popping out of the div like a normal dropdown would behave. I need to keep the horizontal scroll.

How can I solve this?

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d3jy68q7/**

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="nav-scroller bg-body" id="navbarsExample03">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 5</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 6</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 7</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 8</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #212529 !important;
}
.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link, .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar appears because the dropdown's parent container overflows when it opens, as its overflow-y is not hidden. However, as the parent's parent container has overflow hidden, the dropdown menu cannot show, it's hidden behind.

For the dropdown menu to show/pop out, you might move it out of the containers with hidden overflow.

It could be done with JavaScript: get the dropdown container positions, and assign it to the dropdown menu, and add dropdown's height to the dropdown menu, to place it to the bottom (also add fixed position, so that it can pop out of the overflow hidden containers).

Also, as the nav items can scroll, you might also add a scroll listener, and adjust the menu.

Try this:

```js
const myDropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

function adjustDropdownMenu(event) {

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {

    const dropdownContPos = myDropdown.getBoundingClientRect();

    document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").style.cssText = `
        position: fixed;
        left: ${dropdownContPos.left}px;
        top: ${dropdownContPos.height + dropdownContPos.top}px;
    `;
  });
}

myDropdown.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', adjustDropdownMenu);
document.querySelector('.navbar-nav').addEventListener('scroll', adjustDropdownMenu);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav-scroller bg-body" id="navbarsExample03">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 7</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .nav-scroller {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2.75rem;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #212529 !important;
  }
  
  .nav-scroller .nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav .nav-link,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

**multiple dropdowns**

In case you have multiple dropdowns, you can loop each dropdown and assign it event listener, as well as pass the dropdown element, from which then you get its position, and then assign it to the dropdown menu, while on scroll, you can just find the currently opened dropdown, get its parent element and its position, and then do the same:

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-scroller .dropdown');

function position(dropdownMenu, containerPos) {

  dropdownMenu.style.cssText = `
            position: fixed;
            left: ${containerPos.left}px;
            top: ${containerPos.height + containerPos.top}px;
        `;
}

function adjustOnScroll() {
  const openedDropdown = document.querySelector('.nav-scroller .dropdown-menu.show');
  if (openedDropdown) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const containerPos = openedDropdown.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      position(openedDropdown, containerPos);
    });
  }
}

function adjustDropdownMenu(dropdown) {
  return (event) => {
    const containerPos = dropdown.getBoundingClientRect();
    position(dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'), containerPos);
  }
}

dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
  dropdown.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', adjustDropdownMenu(dropdown));
});

document.querySelector('.navbar-nav').addEventListener('scroll', adjustOnScroll);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav-scroller bg-body" id="navbarsExample03">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Link4 Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 7</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-disabled="true">Link 8</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .nav-scroller {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2.75rem;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #212529 !important;
  }
  
  .nav-scroller .nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav .nav-link,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
  .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the JS doesn't work if there's more than 1 dropdown. Any idea why? Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/4qswoc78/

Comment: the principle is roughly the same, only need to loop dropdowns, try the code under _multiple dropdowns_

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I see no horizontal scrolling btw.

well you dont need your `overflow` property on your `.nav-scroller` and `.nav-scroller .nav` selectors :

```css
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
  background-color: #212529 !important;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link, .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-nav .nav-link.show {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Remove both of the properties as seen in the example above you will no longer have the scrolling inside the navbar

And if you want here is a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/41cb2w9h/3/)

Comment: Thank you but you're mistaken. There's a menu-horizontal scrolling which stops working when I remove the properties you suggested. Here's an updated link with more menu items and text-content. Perhaps, you didn't see earlier: https://jsfiddle.net/5gq034fc/